# EntityFunctions absolute value

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EntityFunctions class in my LINQ query as:

```
var a = dbContext.Where(x=>EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(dateA,dateB)<1)
```

However I want an absolute value of the difference, so that I do not have to worry which date is greater.

Can anyone suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
var a = dbContext.Where(x =>  Math.Abs(EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(dateA,dateB)) < 1);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this earlier but got an error because my DateTime was nullable - and I thought there was some problem with using Abs. I just needed to add .Value in the end! My bad! :)